# Sublime duplicate removal (Array)

Tags: database, sublimetext2, duplication

Ran into an issue that I couldnt solve.
Say I have a text file with thousands of entries such as:

```
12.04.2013 krispy
11.2.2013 krispy
11.2.2013 peter
11.2.2013 william
23.4.2014 krispy
```

How can I select and permute unique so that only 1 date for krispy is selected (doesnt matter which), so that the output is:

```
12.04.2013 krispy
11.2.2013 peter
11.2.2013 william
```

Meaning somehow I'm selecting the 2nd value after the " " space character and permuting it to remove the entire line.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Sublime Text 2 on windows, but if there is a solution on linux then I'd be glad to hear it

Comment: Because on bash I would have issued `sort -k2 -u test -o test`, could you use python?

Comment: @enrico.bacis why don't you make that an answer? Maybe include a line about installing gitbash for Windows to get command-line utilities like `sort`...

Comment: Actually because it was requested for sublimetext, but since the OP agreed on checking also other solutions, let's do it.

Comment: @MattDMo Ok, I've done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (normally) not the job of an editor, you should do it in a programming language, but since you agreed to check also other solutions, let's go for it.

### bash

Just use the sort method:

```
sort -k2 -u filename -o filename
```

This will sort lines based on the second column (`-k2`) and return only the ones that are unique for that column (`-u`). You read the file `filename` and output on the file `filename` (to overwrite it).

If you are on a non-unix system you could use [`git-bash`](https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/install-git-bash) or [`cygwin`](https://www.cygwin.com/) to use unix commands.

### python

Otherwise you could use the omnipresent python to accomplish this. Actually sublime text is written in python, so it's trivial to turn this code in a plugin for sublime.

#### removedups.py

```
from fileinput import input
import sys

seen = set()
filename = sys.argv[1]

for line in input(filename, inplace=True):
    date, name = line.split()
    if name not in seen:
        seen.add(name)
        print line,
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
python removedups.py filename
```

Comment: Ill just perform it on one of my Debian machines. Thanks for the sort modifiers to use, silly that I didn't Google that but I had become dependent on sublime there for a while. +1.